# Spring security SAML IDP initiated SSO

Tags: spring-saml

I m new in Spring Security SAML can someone please explain how to implement IDP initiated SSO in spring security by SAML(step by step)
whenever my IDP server is ADFS 
and who will provide metadata Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write your own IdP software?

I would suggest install any open source IdP like Shibboleth and write SAML extension using Spring Security for any customization.

Or please wait for someone who has actually done it, to answer your question.
All the best!